# PHP and cURL: same code but unable to fetch content on existing server conf

Tags: php, linux, ssl, curl, centos

I'm running into some awkward issue when trying to fetch content from a URL.

The issue is the URL returns no response and the http "request header" size is 0.

I've run into similar issue like this on the same website before and have solved it (with some help on StackOverflow).

Previously, the issue was due to their SSL certificate being misconfigured and the solution was to set both CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false. However, it seems that this time, even with these two cURL parameters being set to false, cURL is still having problems fetching from the URL.

other notes:

i.) The web content can be fetched with a regular web browser, even with incognito mode.

ii.) The CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER that I set below is the exact headers sent by the web browser. Whether I set this parameter or not, cURL doesn't return anything (and the "request header" is still zero).

I've later tested the code on a LEMP server with Ubuntu 14.04 (using simply a stock server image provided by a web host) and the code works. So this seems to be a server issue and not a code issue.

the following are the configurations:

---

CentOS 6 LEMP server with PHP 5.3.3 (doesn't work):

```
curl:
    curl 7.19.7
    SSL Version NSS/3.14.0.0

openssl:
    OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
```

CentOS 5 LAMP server with PHP 5.4.40 (doesn't work. this configuration is from the server setup by the shared web hosting provider. I've no control over it.):

```
curl:
    curl 7.38.0
    SSL Version OpenSSL/0.9.8b

openssl:
    OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LEMP server with PHP 5.5.9 (works. this is from the stock server image provided by a VPS web host):

```
curl:
    curl 7.35.0
    SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1f

openssl:
    OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

---

Since I need to make this code work on a shared hosting environment, I wonder if anyone can tell me what cause the difference so I can make a change or request a change if possible.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array(
    'Host: www.example.com',
    'User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT: 1',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer: https://www.example.com/path/to/example.html',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    ));

$url = 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/example';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

print_r( curl_getinfo($ch) );

?>
```

Comment: In your first 2 configs your SSL provider lib and your cURL SSL libs don't seem to match.

Comment: @apokryfos. i) they are blocks copied exact from phpinfo. ii) the second conf is setup by the shared web hosting provider and I have no control over it. If this is the issue, then web hosting provider set it up wrong? I always gussed it has to do with out dated version as opposed to non-matched libs.

Comment: I just find it odd because when PHP is installed the modules loaded are compiled based on what is installed on the system so it's not easy to be able to get the php-curl module installed using a different openssl library version unless there's multiple openssl library versions installed on the system. It just looks odd to me.

Comment: @apokryfos. i) I double checked the shared hosting one. Yes, they are as displayed. ii) do you think it may have to do with this   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#110457   However, I tried the solution on one of the non-working servers and its still the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize. It does not work with SSL versions NSS/3.14.0.0 and OpenSSL/0.9.8b but works with OpenSSL/1.0.1f.

Looking at the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.galottery.com) it can be seen that the host requires at least TLS 1.1, i.e. no support for TLS 1.0 or even lower. Support for TLS 1.1 was added to OpenSSL with version 1.0.1, i.e. it is not available with OpenSSL 0.9.8b. NSS 3.14.0 has support for TLS 1.1 included (just added with version 3.14) but as can be seen from [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1042989) curl on RHEL6/CentOS6 will use TLS 1.0 only by default.

Comment: Wow. It looks like this is the cause. I guess to make it work on shared hosting, I either request to upgrade the SSL or switch hosting plans. Thank you man. You're amazing. You even pin pointed a bug report url.